# Is there anyway to use firebase storage for flutter desktop?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am trying to build a cross platform app. I have used firebase for database. Anyway to use firebase storage for flutter desktop ?(Windows)

Comment: According to https://firebase.flutter.dev/ Firebase Storage is support on macOS desktop. What problem do you run into when using it?

Comment: I want to build for windows dektop

Comment: Any Updates on it? or any way around to use storage with desktop?

Comment: Hi, for anyone who is interested in the official flutterfire desktop. please upvote for the feature request in the link below. thanx!
https://firebase.uservoice.com/forums/948424-general/suggestions/46591750-desktop-windows-linux-macos-support-for-flutte

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no support for running Flutter apps that use Firebase Realtime Database for Windows. Only macOS is supported according to the table on firebase.flutter.dev.

Also see:

- [Flutterfire cli not showing windows and linux as an option for platform to support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73989832/flutterfire-cli-not-showing-windows-and-linux-as-an-option-for-platform-to-suppo)

Comment: Storage is not Database.

Comment: Same answer from the same [table](https://firebase.flutter.dev/) though. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯