# Flutterfire cli not showing windows and linux as an option for platform to support

Tags: windows, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cli

I cannot compile my flutter app since it is not configured for windows, or rather it is not configured Firebase for windows, so the app starts but fails. And I don't understand why when I run `flutterfire configure` it shows what follows.

[image]

Comment: Hi, for anyone who is interested in the official flutterfire desktop. please upvote for the feature request in the link below. thanx!

https://firebase.uservoice.com/forums/948424-general/suggestions/46591750-desktop-windows-linux-macos-support-for-flutte

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*firebaser here*

The [Firebase SDKs for Flutter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup) (colloquially known as [FlutterFire](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire)) work by wrapping the native SDKs for Firebase's primary supported platforms: iOS (now also macOS), Android and Web. While Flutter allows you to build Windows and Linux desktop apps, Firebase does not have SDKs for those platforms.

For some of its products, Firebase supports developing on Windows through its C++/Unity SDKs, but not creating production apps for the platform. At Google I/O 2023 Firebase announced that it started wrapping this C++ SDKs to [provide Windows support **for development workflows** for Flutter developers](https://youtu.be/PsV-wSZ2BCo?t=320) too. No progress has been reported since, but you can follow along on the FlutterFire repo I linked above.

---

There *is* an experimental [`flutterfire_desktop` package](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire_desktop) that implements pure Dart SDKs, but this is experimental and only support Firebase Authentication at the moment.

If you want to use all of Firebase in your Flutter app for Windows and/or Linux, you'll have to either wrap the [REST APIs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest) of the Firebase products you want to use yourself, or use a library that wraps the REST API already. An example of this is the [`firedart` library](https://pub.dev/packages/firedart) that provides basic support for Authentication and Firestore, but there are probably others.